# SSIS export to Excel template - VLOOKUP

Tags: excel, vba, ssis

A client has an exact template that must be used. Due to the formatting I cannot insert the data directly into the template via SSIS.

**Idea:**
Run SSIS as a schedule. It copies the template and populates the information.

I used a "reference" sheet in the same workbook to push all the necessary data to as I could not place it directly in the required template.

VLOOKUPs to the "reference" sheet are used to correctly set the data in the template.

**Issue:** The VLOOKUP does not automatically refresh the data. When I open the workbook the values are the same. If I change a cell in the reference table, the data updates in the VLOOKUPs.

**Solution:** What I need is a way to set the data in SSIS, and have the VLOOKUPs automatically re-check the data when the Excel workbook is opened.

Answer (score 0):

**Resolved**
I have resolved the issue with the following

**Issue**
The VLOOKUPs will not update on open without manually opening/changing an impacted cell

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,Reference!$A2:$B6, 2, FALSE)
```

**Solution Found**
A bit of a hack, but in the Reference worksheet:

1. Added a "Format" row to the template
2. In the VLOOKUP reference column (Reference!$A2) place a formula that will be updated (e.g. "=TODAY()") in the "Format" row

Now whenever the workbook is opened, Reference!$A$2 is updated to today's date. This triggers the VLOOKUPs in the template to update because a value changed in the reference column. The full process is:

1. Template.xlsx (2 sheets: TemplateResults, and Reference)
2. SSIS - Copies Template.xlsx for current run
3. SSIS - Pulls data and places in Template.xlsx - Reference
4. Open CopiedTemplate.xlsx: Reference!$A$2 updates itself to current date. Triggers VLOOKUPs in TemplateResults to update themselves

Comment: vba Macro... useful if the data only needs to be checked/updated when first opened, not every time it is opened. The macro I used is below. Works the same as =TODAY() above, but will only update the value the one time. (see below)

Comment: `Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim dataSheet As Sheet2
    Dim dateCell As Range
    Dim firstValueCell As Range
    Dim sMyString As String
    
    Set dataSheet = Worksheets("Reference")
    Set dateCell = dataSheet.Range("B2")
    Set firstValueCell = dataSheet.Range("A3")
    
    If dateCell = "WAIT" And firstValueCell <> "" Then
        dateCell.Value = "HOLD"
    End If
End Sub`